# When are all my components loaded?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm having a component, which has several children and they might also have some children. I can not predict, if all the children will be loaded, since it depends on the content your looking at. What I want to achieve, is a loading indicator which show while the content is loaded. But I don't want to display a loading indicator for every component, because I'll end up having 10-15 loading indicators.

My idea is that the root parent, displays a loading indicator and once all the children are initialised the loading indicator can disappear. But how can I make sure that all the children are loaded?

Comment: Loading indicator as in some loader for the application until the app is loaded?
And, obviously your app might have server calls and you want to show the loader until they're loaded yeah?

Comment: Something like this: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/928100/19479978/11194b9e-9541-11e6-98bb-4cd3c3313795.gif

Comment: Yes. I have data requests, which I'm waiting for and also a visualisation, which I would like to be loaded, before I remove the loading animation.

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it'll help you through your problem

Answer (score 5):

The children are loaded when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called in `AppComponent`

Comment: Only in the AppComponent? Are from any root of a tree?

Comment: If you only want to know from a component somewhere in your application if its children are loaded, then you can use `ngAfterViewInit()` of this component. If you want to know when all components of your application are loaded, then you need to use `ngAfterViewInit()` of the `AppComponent`, because then all components of your whole application are known to be loaded.

Comment: I need more something what gets fired once all children have fired the ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: Because sometimes I have to wait for data.

Comment: I already responded in the comment where you posted earlier today that that you need a different strategy if you fetch data asynchronously. There is no single hook for when all async calls have completed and there is no generic answer for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment for my question, you can add the loading contents in a div and loader in another div. You can hide/show according to the state.

```
<div *ngIf="loaded"> Your content</div>
<div *ngIf="!loaded"> Loader </div>
```

And, the **loaded** variable you can assign it in the class and change it according to the state.

- If that's something that has child view you can consider about `ngAfterViewInit()`
- If you're fetching data from an api and showing it, accordingly you can assign the **loaded** variable as true when the data is loaded

Initially, assign **loaded** variable as false.

Also, considering your issue on adding the loader in all the components, you can add the loader in the root component and can change the state (true/false) through a service. Then, you have to change the state through component.
And, also subscribe the value of variable from the root component whether to show the loader or content.
Hope this part might help with it - [Component Interaction through a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Comment: Did this answer help you? @tschaka or need further help

Comment: Yes. I think it is going into the right direction. I'm still trying to find a way to simplify it a bit. My biggest problem is, that I don't know if a component is loaded or not. Or to be more accurate, I can't predict it. Because depending on the selected object, a section might be displayed or not.

Comment: "My biggest problem is, that I don't know if a component is loaded or not"
But, What's the issue with this?

Comment: How am I supposed to know if there is maybe still something not loaded or everything is loaded, if I don't know what to expect.

Comment: If that's a component or module, if that's declared or imported in then it loads. So, for the data from the server, use some boolean variable to make sure the data is loaded. So, at the point where data is loaded change the boolean value. Makes sense?