# Angular and calling a JS event only once after document.ready()?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, document-ready

One of the things I'm still hung up on with Angular is understanding all of the lifecycle hooks and when to use what when.

I often need to stick a little plain'ol JS into a component to deal with some DOM issue that, alas, I can't handle via Angular (usually because I'm working within a component that needs to access some elements from a parent component's rendered DOM that we have no access to the Angular code for...I do realize this isn't the 'proper' Angular way but...).

An example right now is a few pages I'm working on that use a component need that needs to hide a DOM element on the page that isn't a part of this component. I need to use JS for this (a whole other story why CSS isn't the solution for this one).

But I only want to do this once the DOM is fully rendered.

Sometimes this seems to work when inserted into `ngAfterViewInit` -- but sometimes not. It seems that there's no guarantee the full DOM is ready using that lifecycle.

Moving that logic into `ngAfterViewChecked` *does* work. However, the issue with `ngAfterViewChecked` is that it's getting called dozens of times on some pages--and the first few times it's called, the DOM isn't even ready. Not the end of the world, but there's no reason for me to be attempting to grab the same DOM object 40 times per page render. I somewhat remedy this by adding a boolean flag to tell this bit of JS to stop running once it finds the DOM elements but that's hacky.

So my question is: What is the `proper` (if there is one) way to handle JS manipulation of the DOM *after* the DOM is fully rendered in the context of an Angular component? Is it to use one of the angular lifecycle events? Something else? Or this whole idea of manipulating DOM objets outside of the component I'm working in just anathema to the 'Angular way' so just isn't something accommodated within Angular?

Comment: @RyanWilson which angular lifecycle hook would I place that in, though? I could, of course, place that in `ngAfterViewChecked` and I suppose that'd be a bit more efficient than what I'm presently doing (looking for the DOM object).

Comment: Check this post - [when-are-all-my-components-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807831/when-are-all-my-components-loaded)

Comment: @RyanWilson the catch is the particular DOM objects I need to manipulate are coming from a parent component rather than child. Also `ngAfterViewInit()` doesn't appear to equate to a fully rendered DOM at times.